# Displaying a score on HUD in Flash AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, hud, dynamic-text

I really need help (explanation) on using dynamic text in Flash. I get stuck when trying to display the current score on HUD in my game. I'm still new in Flash so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of current score displayed by the text field `currentScore`
when someone clicks on the stage:

```
var p:int = 0; // score points

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    p++;
    currentScore.text = String(p);
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickHandler);
```